# What qualities should one look for when choosing Egg cooking gear?

Tags: equipment, eggs, scrambled-eggs

Stainless Steel seems to be all the rage in cooking stores these days, yet frying eggs on one leads to an extremely messy cleanup situation, assuming you can get it out without breaking it. Scrambling eggs works fine but the cleanup is brutal, even with loads of butter.

My goal is to cook/fry eggs in a pan, Teflon seems the obvious choice; but it quickly starts to flake off making the food uneatable.

What type of pan and associated tools (spoon, spatula, etc) should I look for? I’d also like to avoid using loads of butter, PAM, and oils, seeing as eggs have enough fat and cholesterol already.

Comment: Interesting point, though my primary worry is not about it flaking off on it own, but from repeated scraping from utilities: spatula, spoon, etc... Any ways around that?

Comment: @Michael- make that an answer instead of a comment and I'll vote you up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern non-stick pans should not have problems with coatings flaking off. Spend $50 on a non-stick pan and it will last you for a very long time. Coatings on good pans should hold up to any non-metallic utensils. Very expensive pans suggest that you can hit them with a hammer and not hurt the surface.

Comment: Did a bit of poking around, and also heard that a rubber spatula works quite well.

Comment: Heat proof silicone spatula!!

Answer (score 1):

We love our cast iron skillets for eggs.

Given some oil, fried eggs simply never stick. If there isn't enough oil you have to push them a bit to get them loose.

Scrambled eggs stick a bit, but cleanup is a few seconds with water and a scouring pad.

And that's for $20.